# How can I clear the text of file input field after upload?

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs

I am using Laravel 9 with Inertia.js and Vue 3.
However, I think the backend really doesn't matter.

The problem is that when I upload a file as outline in the tutorial and reset the form, the file name still remains on the form.(After the submission, the same page shows)

Here's basically what I followed.
https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads

Here's some code snippets

```
<input type="file" multiple @input="formFiles.report_pdfs = $event.target.files">



const formFiles = useForm({
report_pdfs: []
});

const uploadReportFiles = () => {

    formFiles.post(route('uploadReports',{surveyId: props.survey.id}), {
        preserveScroll: true,
        onSuccess: () => {
          formFiles.reset();
        },

    });
};
```

I've tried many different things but here's a few things I tried.
1.

```
onSuccess: () => {
          formFiles.report_pdfs = []; // also set it to null
        },
```

2. If I set the following option, it clears but that's not what I want to do. I want to preserve the state and just clear the form completely.

> ```
> formFiles.post(route('uploadReports',{surveyId: props.survey.id}), {
>     preserveScroll: true,
>     preserveState: false, // added this line and it works but that's not what I want
>     onSuccess: () => {
>       formFiles.reset();
>     },
>
> });
> ```

I struggled with this for several hours so I decided to ask for help from the community.
You input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this;

Since you are initializing the empty array `report_pdfs` to store multiple images, you could instead SWITCH between two buttons by checking the length of the `report_pdfs` array once an image has been uploaded.

if an image is NOT uploaded:

```
<template v-if="!formFiles.report_pdfs.length > 0">
    <label> Please Upload an Image </label>
    <input type="file" multiple @input="formFiles.report_pdfs = $event.target.files">
</template>
```

If an image IS uploaded:

```
<template v-if="formFiles.report_pdfs.length > 0">
    <label> {{ formFiles.report_pdfs.length }} Images Uploaded </label>
    <input type="file" multiple @input="formFiles.report_pdfs = $event.target.files">
</template>
```

**Have both the above codes in the design** so that when the `report_pdfs` array changes, it will automatically change the buttons based on the length of it. The length will be checked with Vue's v-if directive.

Regardless, both buttons will still point to the same `report_pdfs` array so it can be used.

Hope this helps!